# Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, agent

> springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.navin.friends.config.JPAConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>           at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:82) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:348) ~[eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>           ... 21 common frames omitted
>       Jun 01, 2017 5:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>       SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.navin.friends.config.JPAConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>           at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:82)
>           at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:348)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>           ... 21 more

```
Jun 01, 2017 5:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 01, 2017 5:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/remember-friends] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 01, 2017 5:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 01, 2017 5:53:26 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/remember-friends] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 01, 2017 5:53:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]

    @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws IOException {
            EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
            vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFacotryBean= new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.navin.friends.domain.entity");
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setJpaProperties(getJPAProperties());
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("friends");
            entityManagerFacotryBean.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());
            return entityManagerFacotryBean;

        }
```

Comment: Can any one help me regarding the above issue.

Comment: a big error dump is not enough to help provide assistance, can you describe what is causing the error and what you have tried so far to fix it

Comment: When i am starting my app, I am getting the above error. Grey colour is my code. I am passing vm argument = clean install tomcat7:run.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include a spring-instrument.jar agent as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            <argLine>
                 -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.framework.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.framework.version}.jar"
        </argLine>
            <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

( replace ${spring.framework.version} and ${settings.localRepository} with your values )

and of course an AspecJ Maven plugin as:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.3</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>                     
             <goals>
                 <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                 <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
             </goals>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For AspectJ to work, you would also need to add an aspectjrt dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
</dependency>
```